# Obtener última ID o la más alta en TextView (Sqlite)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tengo una `Sqlite` donde guardo las notas que creo con una **id** y lo que quiero es recibir la última **id** que haya en la lista (o la **id** con el número más alto).

He hecho lo siguiente, pero obtengo todas las **id**:

`Sqlite`:

```
public String CantidadCategorias() {
    String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_NOTAS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    List lista1 = new ArrayList();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String id = cursor.getString(0);
            lista1.add(id);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return String.valueOf(lista1);
}
```

`Activity`

```
 public void contadorCategorias() {

        final String list = mDatabase.CantidadCategorias();
        txt_01.setText(list.toString());
    }
```

Lo que obtengo ahora mismo, si por ejemplo creo dos notas es:

> [1, 2]

Y lo que necesito es obtener solamente **2**, que sería la última **id** o la más alta.

Si no me equivoco el error es que estoy creando una lista y no lo necesito, pero no sé como hacerlo correctamente. Lo que quiero básicamente es un contador para saber cuantas notas hay y se me he ocurrido recibir la **id**.

Comment: Puedes probar modificando la consulta SQL por `select MAX(id)  from TABLE_NOTAS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más lógico sería modificar tu consulta para obtener un único resultado.

Sin modificar demasiado tu código una opción rápida es:

```
public String CategoriaMax() {
        String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_NOTAS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List lista1 = new ArrayList();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        String id ="";
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                id = cursor.getString(0);
                lista1.add(id);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
       // return String.valueOf(lista1);
       return id; //lleva el último valor
    }


 public void contadorCategorias() {

        final String maxId = mDatabase.CategoriaMax();
        txt_01.setText(maxId);
    }
```

Le he dado un nombre diferente para no pisar la anterior por si la usas en otros sitios.

Para completar la respuesta hay que cambiar la consulta y preguntar por el número de registros que contiene la tabla:

"select count(*) as total from tabla_notas;"

Comment: Se me olvidó declarar la variable id fuera del bucle, ya lo he corregido, espero que ahora te funcione.

Comment: Funciona pero tengo un problema ajeno a tu respuesta, es que cuando borro una nota, al añadir una nueva sigue sumando id, por lo tanto mi idea de contador de notas que hay no sirve. Es decir, si creo dos, recibo 2, pero si borro una y añado otra nueva, recibo 3, ya que la **id** sigue aumentando.. Sabes alguna otra forma de realizar el contador? Es decir, que me cuente las columnas que hay

Comment: Si, la consulta a la base de datos sería: "select count (*) as total from mitabla;" . El valor de total sería las notas que tienes en la tabla.

Comment: Exactamente lo que necesitaba! Añade eso a la pregunta y marco como solución, gracias :)

Comment: Ahora la edito :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes traer solo el registro más alto, es simplemente cambiar la query.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM TableName ORDER BY Id DESC
```

De esta manera te traes los registros ordenados por Id de mayor a menor y el TOP 1 es solo traer el primero de ellos, es decir, el más alto.

Luego no tendrías que hacer un bucle ya que solo trae un registro.

Saludos